# Oracle - Subqueries reduction in Merge

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, oracle11gr2

I'm having a `MERGE` with a `subquery` to get and ID, and I'm wondering if the `subquery in the NOT MATCHED statement` is always executed or not.

```
        MERGE INTO CAR_STOCK st
        USING CAR_PRODUCTO pro
        ON (pro.id = st.producto_id AND pro.ean = ?)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET st.stockActual = ?
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (stockActual, local_id, producto_id, activo)
        VALUES (?, ?, (SELECT id FROM car_producto WHERE ean = ?), 'S');
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** the `?` are because I'm using `JDBC` in a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: It would execute when not matched. Whats the doubt here. You explicitly defied activity which is needed to be done when joins you mentioned satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

No need for subquery, You could simply refer to `pro.id` in `insert` part, like here:

```
merge into t1 using t2 on (t1.a = t2.a)
  when matched then update set t1.b = t2.b
  when not matched then insert (a, b)
  values (0, t2.b)
```

---

Test data and `merge` result:

```
create table t1 as (select 1 a, 'a01' b from dual);
create table t2 as (select 1 a, 'a05' b from dual union all select 2 a, 'bxx' b from dual );

     A  B
------  ---
     1  a05
     0  bxx
```